# How to replace a single index of a string for a number?

Tags: javascript

I want to replace vowels in a string with numbers, but I can not get it working.
This code I am showing, I am only doing the vowel "e", here is my code:

```
var string = prompt("Enter anything with letters only");
console.log("You wrote: " + string);

for(k=0; k<string.length; k++){

  if(string[k]=="a"){
    console.log(string[k]);            
  }
  if(string[k]=="e" || string[k]=="E"){
    console.log("found: " + string[k]);
    string[k] = "2" ;  // Here is where I am trying to replace the vowels "e" to value 2
  }
  if(string[k]=="i" || string[k]=="I"){
    console.log("found: " + string[k]);
  }
  if(string[k]=="o" || string[k]=="O"){
    console.log("found: " + string[k]);
  }
  if(string[k]=="u" || string[k]=="U"){
    console.log("found: " + string[k]);
  }
}
console.log(string);
```

Please note I am very new to javascript, this is why I am doing simple `for` loop exercises with no special comands or shorcuts.

I have tried: `string[k] = 2` and also `string[k] = (variable with the value 2)`

Any sugestions?

Answer (score 4):

Strings are immutable. You could use an array and change the items/characters. Later you could join the array back to a string.

```js
var string = prompt("Enter anything with letters only"),
    array = string.split('');

console.log("You wrote: " + string);

for (k = 0; k < array.length; k++) {
    if (array[k] == "a") {
        console.log(string[k]);
    }
  
    if (array[k] == "e" || array[k] == "E") {
        console.log("found: " + array[k]);
        array[k] = "2";
    }
    if (array[k] == "i" || array[k] == "I") {
        console.log("found: " + array[k]);
    }
    if (array[k] == "o" || array[k] == "O") {
        console.log("found: " + array[k]);
    }
    if (array[k] == "u" || array[k] == "U") {
        console.log("found: " + array[k]);
    }
}

string = array.join('');

console.log(string);
```

A different approach by using a regular expression and an [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) for replacing the characters with [`String#replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace).

```js
var string = prompt("Enter anything with letters only");

string = string.replace(/[aeiou]/gi, c => ({ a: 1, e: 2, i: 3, o: 4, u: 5}[c.toLowerCase()]));

console.log(string);
```

Comment: `c => 'aeiou'.indexOf(c.toLowerCase())+1`?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts, the object offers an arbitrary value for replacement, but the string is the shortest way.

Comment: Ah true, arbitrary value is an advantage of your approach.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Regular Expressions

```
var string=prompt("Enter anything with letters only");
console.log("You wrote: " + string);

string = string.replace(/a/g, 1);
string = string.replace(/e/g, 2);
string = string.replace(/i/g, 3);
string = string.replace(/o/g, 4);
string = string.replace(/u/g, 5);
console.log(string);
```

this may not be the best way to do it, it's not looking very clean. The modifier g stands for global-search, it will find all occurences.

Comment: Might want to include the `i` flag as well, and convert to a Stack snippet to prove it works.

Answer (score 0):

you can use regular expressions for that

```js
var string = prompt("Enter anything with letters only");

console.log("You wrote: " + string);

string = string.replace(/a/gi, 1);

string = string.replace(/e/gi, 2);

string = string.replace(/i/gi, 3);

string = string.replace(/o/gi, 4);

string = string.replace(/u/gi, 5);

console.log(string);
```

`gi` makes the search global and case insensitive but if you insist on using a loop you can do this

```js
var string = prompt("Enter anything with letters only");

console.log("You wrote: " + string);

var string2 = "";

for (var k = 0; k < string.length; k++) {

  if (string[k] == "a") {
    console.log(string[k]);
    string2 += "1";
  } else if (string[k] == "e" || string[k] == "E") {
    console.log("found: " + string[k]);
    string2 += "2";
  } else if (string[k] == "i" || string[k] == "I") {
    console.log("found: " + string[k]);
    string2 += "3";
  } else if (string[k] == "o" || string[k] == "O") {
    console.log("found: " + string[k]);
    string2 += "4";
  } else if (string[k] == "u" || string[k] == "U") {
    console.log("found: " + string[k]);
    string2 += "5";
  } else {
    string2 += string[k];
  }
}

console.log(string2);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Prompt: type in word, example: "lolvowelslol" & display this in console
var str = prompt("Enter anything with letters only");
console.log("You wrote: " + string);

//Type in what wordt you want to find
var word = "vowels";

//Regex: Find the index range of the word, than replace it with the second string
var result = str.replace(word, "123456")
```

**Bonus:**

```
var str = "vvowels";
var word = "vowels";
var toNumbers = function(word) {
    var numbers = "";
    for(var i=0;i<word.length;i++) numbers += i+1;
    return numbers;
};
var result = str.replace(word, toNumbers(word));
```

Comment: Please detail and explain what you did

Comment: Better now? I personally find it easyier to understand without comments. Especially in this case where the answer to his question requires only 1 function.

It's also better to use the replace function to the full wordt. Else their is a change when your input is for example vvowels. The system will replace the first v to a number as well.